# Spring boot Security Config - authenticationManager must be specified

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

Here's my main Application config

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
                .banner((environment, aClass,  printStream) ->
                        System.out.println(stringBanner()))
                .run();
    }
}
```

And here's my spring security application config.

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private WebServiceAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private TokenProcessingFilter authTokenProcessingFilter;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) // Restful hence stateless
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler) // Notice the entry point
                .and()
                .addFilter(authTokenProcessingFilter) // Notice the filter
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/api/auth")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/greeting")
                .hasRole("USER");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Here's my TokenProcessingFilter that extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter  for my custom authentication filter

```
@Component
public class TokenProcessingFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = this.getAsHttpRequest(request);
        String authToken = this.extractAuthTokenFromRequest(httpRequest);
        String userName = TokenUtils.getUserNameFromToken(authToken);
        if (userName != null) {/*
            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userName);*/
            UserDetails userDetails = fakeUserDetails();
            if (TokenUtils.validateToken(authToken, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails.getUsername(), userDetails.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpRequest));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private HttpServletRequest getAsHttpRequest(ServletRequest request){
        if (!(request instanceof HttpServletRequest)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Expecting an HTTP request");
        }
        return (HttpServletRequest) request;
    }


    private String extractAuthTokenFromRequest(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        /* Get token from header */
        String authToken = httpRequest.getHeader("x-auth-token");
        /* If token not found get it from request parameter */
        if (authToken == null) {
            authToken = httpRequest.getParameter("token");
        }
        return authToken;
    }

    private UserDetails fakeUserDetails(){
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("user","password");

        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> auth= new ArrayList<>();
        auth.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
        return  new User("user","password",auth);
    }
}
```

however when running the application, I encounter this exception message. What am I missing?

> An exception occured while running. null: InvocationTargetException:
>   Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException:
>   Unable to start embedded Tomcat: Error creating bean with name
>   'tokenProcessingFilter' defined in file
>   [C:\Users\kyel\projects\app\target\classes\org\app\testapp\security\TokenProcessingFilter.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authenticationManager must be
>   specified

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to set the `AuthenticationManager` on `TokenProcessingFilter`. Instead of using @Component on TokenProcessingFilter, just create it in the SecurityConfig.

```
@Bean
TokenProcessingFilter tokenProcessingFilter() {
  TokenProcessingFilter tokenProcessingFilter = new TokenProcessingFilter();
  tokenProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
  return tokenProcessingFilter;
}
```

and

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  ...
  .addFilter(tokenProcessingFilter())
```

Comment: Why creating a bean at all ? If then calling the method explicitly ?

Comment: What is this magic authenticationManager() call?

Answer (score 2):

In order to keep Component annotation you have to override setAuthenticationManager from AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter and autowire the parameter like this:

```
@Component
public class TokenProcessingFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    //...

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    //...

}
```